# Render ASP .NET MVC ActionResult to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to render the FileContentResult's (.png files in my case) into a base64 strings to return them into json.

I've found an interesting approach from here: http://approache.com/blog/render-any-aspnet-mvc-actionresult-to/ , that supposedly doing what i need, but when I'm trying to do something like

```
public async ActionResult GetUsers()
{    
        ...
        var query = from user in otherUsers
                    join file in allFiles on user.Profile.Id equals file.Profile.Id into usersWithFiles
                    from userWithFile in usersWithFiles.DefaultIfEmpty(new File(){Content = new byte[0], ContentType = "image/png"})
                    select new UserFriendModel { Id = user.Id, UserName = user.UserName, ProfileId = user.Profile.Id, File = File(userWithFile.Content, userWithFile.ContentType).Capture(ControllerContext) };

        return Json(query.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm getting

> System.Web.HttpException:"OutputStream is not available when a custom
>   TextWriter is used" thrown at result.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
>   line.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file (png image) in a separate query, transform the data into text format by using your text writer, and then inject it into your data model.

Some psudo code like this:

```
var file = GetFileQuery();
var fileString = TextWriter.Convert(file);
var query = from user in otherUsers
    join file in allFiles on user.Profile.Id equals file.Profile.Id into usersWithFiles
    from userWithFile in usersWithFiles.DefaultIfEmpty(new File(){Content = new byte[0], ContentType = "image/png"})
    select new UserFriendModel { Id = user.Id, UserName = user.UserName, ProfileId = user.Profile.Id, File = fileString };
```

Another way to do it is to use 2 different action to handle the request. First action returns all the normal data for your data model, and 2nd action only returns you the image. This way you have more flexibility with your image format, i.e. you can return it in OutputStream as PNG image (without explicit serialization/deserialization).

That's my 2 cents.

Henry